# How to brighten Textbox when it is focused?

Tags: css

How can I make a bright effect when a textbox is focused?

[Twitter](http://www.twitter.com)'s login page has implemented the brightening text boxes already.

I wonder the way to implement it.

Any ideas? pure CSS? or some javascript to handle focus event and addClass removeClass with it?

I prefer jQuery way of implementing javascript stuffs rather than implementing with pure javascript :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Twitter implements this with a simple CSS3 box-shadow:

```
input:focus {
    box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) inset, 0 0 10px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9)
}
```

There is no Javascript needed to handle style changes when focusing an element.

Comment: Which is why you shouldn't blindly use it :) Put your own styles in-- I'm just showing you how Twitter uses the CSS :focus selector to do it.

Comment: Which browser are you using to test? please note that in order to work properly, it requires a modern browser (not IE6 to 8)

Comment: you can fine tune the colors (rgb) in the above style def to suit your visual preference. But generally this is the most appropriate way to achieve what you asked.

Comment: If you just want a way to highlight the textbox, consider something like `border: 1px solid red` or similar. Only you will know what will make your site look the best :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also write function on onFocus event of the textbox. And inside that function just change the css class of the textfield. Some thing like this
  `<input type=Text onfocus=change()/><script>function change(){// Code to change the class}</script>`
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since your question was tagged with jQuery, and considered catching the focus event, how about:

```
$("#yourTb").focus(function(){
    $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
});
```

Just don't forget to:

```
$("#yourTb").blur(function () {
    $(this).css("background-color", "white");
});
```

Comment: This can be done in CSS without any Javascript at all, let alone jQuery.

Comment: @Interrobang - yes, it *can* be done, but the question was tagged with jQuery, so this is hardly an inappropriate answer.

Comment: It does not make it any more correct. Not only is Javascript heavy-handed for the solution, but you are now mixing presentational style into business logic. At a minimum, jQuery could be used to toggle a class instead of blindly setting CSS attributes.

Comment: @Interrobang - so using jQuery to set a css property based on focus and blur is `mixing presentational style into business logic`.  I think it's clear you don't know what you're talking about.  Also, you might mention to OP that the :focus selector is not supported in IE7 and below.  That may or may not be relevant